# "Sapply" function in R counterpart in MATLAB to convert a code from R to MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning

I want to convert the code in R to MATLAB (not to executing the R code in MATLAB).
The code in R is as follows:

```r
data_set <- read.csv("lab01_data_set.csv")

# get x and y values
x <- data_set$x
y <- data_set$y

# get number of classes and number of samples
K <- max(y)
N <- length(y)

# calculate sample means
sample_means <- sapply(X = 1:K, FUN = function(c) {mean(x[y == c])})

# calculate sample deviations
sample_deviations <- sapply(X = 1:K, FUN = function(c) {sqrt(mean((x[y == c] - sample_means[c])^2))})
```

To implement it in MATLAB I write the following:

```matlab
%% Reading Data

% read data into memory
X=readmatrix("lab01_data_set(ViaMatlab).csv");

% get x and y values
x_read=X(1,:);
y_read=X(2,:);

% get number of classes and number of samples
K = max(y_read);
N = length(y_read);

% Calculate sample mean - 1st method
% funct1 = @(c) mean(c);
% G1=findgroups(y_read);
% sample_mean=splitapply(funct1,x_read,G1)

% Calculate sample mean - 2nd method
for m=1:3
sample_mean(1,m)=mean(x(y_read == m));
end
sample_mean;

% Calculate sample deviation - 2nd method
for m=1:3
sample_mean=mean(x(y_read == m));
sample_deviation(1,m)=sqrt(mean((x(y_read == m)-sample_mean).^2));
sample_mean1(1,m)=sample_mean;
end
sample_deviation;
sample_mean1;
```

As you see I get how to use a for loop in MATLAB instead of `sapply` in R (as 2nd method in code), but do not know how to use a function (Possibly `splitaplly` or any other).

PS: Do not know how to upload the data, so sorry for that part.

Comment: What is the problem with the code? It looks OK on first read. Please be explicit about your problem, see [ask].

Comment: By the way, you can use `std(x)` to get the standard deviation of `x`. No need to code that manually.

Comment: My question is, whether there is any specific function in MATLAB working exactly or somehow like "sapply" in R? If yes, how?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Using `std` gives different answers than the above formula. 
`sample_deviations=arrayfun(@(c) std(x_read(y_read==c)),1:K)
sample_deviations =

    1.2013    0.8392    1.2024`
While
`sample_deviations=arrayfun(@(c) sqrt(mean((x_read(y_read==c)-sample_means(c)).^2)) ,1:K)
sample_deviations =

    1.1862    0.8251    1.1904`

Comment: Yes, true, `std` computes the unbiased estimate of the standard deviation by dividing by N-1, rather than dividing by N like your code does. It’s called the [Bessel correction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction). I’d go with `std`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MATLAB equivalent to R `sapply` is [`arrayfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) - and its relatives `cellfun`, `structfun` and `varfun` depending on what data type your input is.

For example, in R:

```
> sapply(1:3, function(x) x^2)
[1] 1 4 9
```

is equivalent to MATLAB:

```
>>> arrayfun(@(x) x^2, 1:3)

ans =

     1    4    9
```

Note that if the result of the function you pass to `arrayfun`, `cellfun` etc. doesn't have identical type or size for every input, you'll need to specify `'UniformOutput', 'false'` .

Comment: Using above-mentioned function the equivalent code for in R:
`sample_means <- sapply(X = 1:K, FUN = function(c) {mean(x[y == c])})`
will be in MATLAB as follows:
`sample_mean=arrayfun(@(c) mean(x_read(y_read==c)),1:K)`